# Check of listview contains a specific number

Tags: c#, listview

I have the following problem: I want to check if the reservation number already exists in my listview.

I have the following code to add a reservation to the listview.

```
 reservations.Add(new Reservation(nameTextbox.Text, lastnameTextBox.Text, gendercomboBox.SelectedText, Convert.ToInt32(ageNumericUpDown.Value), Convert.ToInt32(kamercomboBox.SelectedIndex) + 1, Convert.ToInt32(quantityUpDown.Value), true));
 reserveringListView.Items.Clear();
 foreach (Reservation reservation in reservations)
 {
     if (!reserveringListView.Items.Contains(reservation.roomnumber))
     {
         ListViewItem livi = new ListViewItem(reservation.name);
         livi.SubItems.Add(reservation.lastname);
         livi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(reservation.gender));
         livi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(reservation.age));
         livi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(reservation.quantity));
         livi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(reservation.roomnumber));
         reserveringListView.Items.Add(livi);
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Its impossible to reserve")
     }
}
```

When i try to test this code i get the following error: Cannot convert from int to System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<T>.Contains`([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)) method expects an argument of type `T` (`System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem`) in your case. But you try to pass an `int` to that method. Thats why you get the error.

In your case I would create a `HashSet<int>` and store `reservation.roomnumber` in it, so you can look up next time, if the `roomnumber` is already there.

Example:

```
reserveringListView.Items.Clear();
HashSet<int> roomCheck = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (Reservation reservation in reservations)
{
    if (roomCheck.Add(reservation.roomnumber))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: added an example

Answer (score 2):

You should change your `if` statement, because you check if `ListView.Items` contains `int`. You can't do this and, also, inside `if` you add `roomnumber` as `string` (but you check if it is in `ListView.Items` as `int`). Your `if` statement should be:

```
if (!reserveringListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any((i) => i.SubItems[5].Text == Convert.ToString(reservation.roomnumber)))
```

Maybe I made mistake with index in `SubItems`. You should check it and if there is mistake write a comment please.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are giving the .Contains method an int parameter, while it only accepts a ListViewItem as parameter

try something like:

```
if (!reserveringListView.Items.Any(litem => litem.SubItems[5].Value == reservation.roomnumber))
{

}
```

Comment: .Any after Items doesnt work for me is it possible that i need to import something like Windows.Forms.Something?

Comment: should be `using System.Linq;`

Comment: this will not work, since you compare `string` and `int`, you need to convert `reservation.roomnumber` to `string` or `.Value` to `int`

Comment: To use `Any()` you should cast `Items` to `IEnumerable`.